# Switch to next tab with middle click in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there a way to get Firefox to switch to the next tab when you click the middle mouse button (regardless of where on the screen the mouse pointer is)?

I can't find an add-on that does this. Thanks

Comment: you could try mapping your middle click to the expression `Ctrl + N` in your mouse software settings (if the mouse manufacturer provides options for button bindings), but you cannot make it application specific, so any app you middle click in will attempt to respond to Ctrl + N however it is designed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware issue. You have to use your "mouse" utilities. I use Logitech Mouse, and set my wheel for volume when pushed to the side.

You would use the software for your mouse to run a macro that you specify.

Else: search "AutoHotKey" and create your own macro using the tutorials on their website. I've just found this and it's great. But you have to be a hobby programmer to enjoy it or at least an enthusiast.

Other remedy: Ctrl + Tab does this too. You could use these key notions to put use towards a macro via mouseware or the AutoHotKey, mentioned above, and apply it to mouse function-ability.